# Why my macbook 2015 13 inch hums when working with latest Xcode?

Tags: macbook-pro, xcode, performance

What may be the cause of this? It happens every time when I build the app on either simulator or device.

Should i clean sth or reset my harddrive?

using **High Sierra** and **Xcode 9.2**

**EDIT:**

It is enough to open Xcode and it hums the same way.

Answer (score 3):

The 2015 MacBook Pro uses a Solid State drive, so there's nothing on it that going to "hum."

In fact, the only *mechanical* component in the MacBook Pro (besides the keys and LCD hinge, of course) is the *fan*.  The fan may be spinning up due to the increased load put on the CPU.  Additionally, it may be clogged with dust or the bearing is simply defective.

Try giving it a cleaning and see if the problem goes away.  There's no need to "reset" your drive as this would have no effect.

Comment: So I try to clean it up and let you know if it helped;) I have the same second macbook and it doesnt work like that;)

Comment: You could also try running xcode with the bottom cover off and when the fan starts, stop it with your finger.  If the hum stops - it's the bearing.

Comment: Also xcode compiling takes a lot of course so the fans will make more noise when that happens.